# Why is the default value for max_features in RandomForestClassifier different than the one in RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn

In `RandomForestClassifier` the default value for `max_features` is `sqrt(n_features)` and in `RandomForestRegressor` it is `n_features`, any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an heuristic based on empirical results. On average, it seems to be a better choice, as a default setting, to  set max_features=sqrt(n_features) for classification and max_features=n_features for regression.

This heuristic stems from this paper : http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/9357/1/geurts-mlj-advance.pdf

In any case, it is of course always a better idea to cross-validate this parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! If I am using the random forest with max_features=n_features and bootstrap=False, would it be correct to say that essentially it behaves like a single decision tree (only with a lot of computation overhead)

Comment: Yes, in that case all trees are the same (modulo some ties that may happen when looking for the best splits).

Comment: If max_features=n_features, then the random subspace method isn't even used?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you may need to set:

```
max_features = 'sqrt'
```

Instead of the suggested:

```
max_features=sqrt(n_features)
```

depending on the version you are running.